# Is one bash shellshock fix tar file for SLES bad?

Tags: bash, suse, readline, shellshock

```
SERVER:/home/user # rpm -Uvh --test readline-5.1-24.4.7406.0.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
warning: readline-5.1-24.4.7406.0.PTF.898762.i586.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID b37b98a9
error: Failed dependencies:
    readline = 5.0-9 is needed by (installed) readline-devel-5.0-9  

SERVER:/home/user # rpm -qa | grep -i readl*
readline-5.0-9
perl-TermReadKey-2.30-2
readline-devel-5.0-9  

SERVER:/home/user # tar -xvf ssbash10GA-i386.tar
bash-3.1-24.4.7406.0.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
readline-5.1-24.4.7406.0.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
SERVER:/home/user #
```

It looks like the readline-devel is missing from ssbash10GA-i386.tar from:

https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=nNXClbWqawg~

**Question:** am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# rpm -Uvh --test readline-5.1-24.4.7406.0.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    readline = 5.0-9 is needed by (installed) readline-devel-5.0-9
```

means, that you have a readline-devel package installed of version 5.0.9 and the PTF you are trying to install would upgrade the main package only and not the `-devel` one as well. Which could cause problems once you tried to build something that uses readline since it would use the header files from a different version than the one it would be then linked against (which is why the dependency is there).

Hence your understanding seems to be correct.

Comment: But the readline-devel package isn't in the corresponding TAR file that SUSE officially provided, this means that they forgot to put the readlin-devel in the TAR?

Comment: Yes, it would seem so.

Comment: I sent a mail one hour ago to bfox [at] gnu.org,chet [at] ins.cwru.edu,security [at] suse.com,info [at] suse.com about this, but still no reply

Comment: @thequestionthequestion well, in the first place I think you should have contacted the vendor through the regular channels - customer support or bugzilla.suse.com. And why would you mail anybody at gnu.org or ins.cwru.edu because of your problems with a largely unsupported enterprise product? I would expect them to ignore you (or put you on a spam list).

Comment: I found the first two e-mails in the RPM as authors. :)

Comment: But those are authors of the software as such - you can be pretty sure they don't care about packages from any distribution. If you wanted author of the packages, distributions usually keep a changelog for each package. Use `rpm -q --changelog package` to display it.

Comment: Thanks, I fwd-ed it to: werner [at] suse.de,alnovak [at] suse.de

Comment: @thequestionthequestion well, as I mentioned earlier, you should channel these issues through bugzilla or customer support (and not directly to the persons you find in the changelog). As you can read in darix's answer, the problem has been resolved already when you asked.

Answer (score 2):

The PTF was replaced by a normal update in the mean time. Just use `zypper` or `yast` to install it.

Comment: Please clarify a little bit deeper. (I didn't gave the -1)

Comment: The PTF was replaced by a normal update in the mean time. just use zypper or yast to install it.